# Where can I find official information or contacts about IOTA Foundation?

Tags: foundation

I was looking for an official contact to get in touch with the IOTA Foundation staff. I found many community websites with a lot of useful information, but those are all unofficial.

I wasn't able to find anything contact on the official website (that I believe is iota.org).

Comment: I guess that mainly depends on what you consider *official*.

Comment: @Helmar I consider official an email address owned and managed that official employes of IOTA foundation.

Comment: Then you should include that into your question via [edit] that you're talking about the IOTA foundation. Otherwise it's no wonder that people guess what you're meaning and provide answers like the one you got.

Comment: @Helmar just to be sure, is the IOTA foundation the main company that controls the IOTA currency?

Comment: The foundation is a [German nonprofit](https://blog.iota.org/iota-foundation-fb61937c9a7e). As far as I know there is no "company that controls the IOTA currency."

Comment: @Helmar probably the word "control" is misused would it be better if I say "company that WORKS on the IOTA currency"?

Answer (score 2):

The community and developers are active on a plethora of social media communities:

- slack (owned and run by devs): http://iotatangle.slack.com/
- reddit (modded by devs): http://reddit.com/r/iota
- official website: http://iota.org
- twitter accounts: https://twitter.com/DomSchiener, https://twitter.com/DavidSonstebo

Comment: well, in this case you should also add the twitter accounts and facebook. These are not the official channel I'm looking for. Plus they don't always reply to messages sent via those channels. Plus sometimes there is the need to communicate sensitive data. So those channels are not the best way to do this.

Comment: If you want to report a sensitive security issue, write directly to david `at` iota `dot` org or dom `at` iota `dot` org Source: Asked on Slack and they responded.

Comment: I'd like to add also contact at iota dot org. Also from slack. But there's no way to retrieve this emails if not from slack.